# Database password revealed in PHP error_log?

Tags: 8, database, security, log-messages, symfony-services

Noticed some errors while updating to Drupal 8.9.11. As I'm reviewing I come across the following. Replaced the actual password with PASSWORD below.

Is this intentional or a bug? I can't see why the db password should be printed. Or could this be a PHP misconfiguration? Running PHP 7.3.25 and mysql 5.7.32 on a Cpanel server *without* Composer/Drush.

I'm also not sure what the error is trying to tell me. I only see this logged a handful of times over the last year. If anyone is able to help, thank you.

```
[08-Dec-2020 07:12:14 UTC] PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php on line 79 #0 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php(416): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'site_live', '>PASSWORD...', Array)
#1 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(374): Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection::open(Array)
#2 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(169): Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection('default', 'default')
#3 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default')
#4 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(79): call_user_func_array('Drupal\\Core\\Dat...', Array)
#5 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(173): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'database')
#6 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(212): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('database', 1)
#7 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(62): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array)
#8 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(173): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'cache.container')
#9 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(544): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.container')
#10 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(910): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getCachedContainerDefinition()
#11 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(477): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer()
#12 /home/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(707): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot()
#13 /home/site/public_html/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#14 {main}
```